# What is the function to upload images in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

I want to upload an image in database and also into a specific folder. I studied many tutorials but I did not find specific answer. So please help me. I tried `$request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is happening? Do you encounter bugs? Please provide more background.

Comment: it is my view code.....{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@uploadImage','file'=>true, 'method'=>'post'))) !!}
{!! Form::label('file','File') !!}
{!! Form::file('image') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}
{!! Form::open() !!}      and this is my controller........ public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        $filename = $request['image'];
        $destinationPath = 'view/images';
        Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        return "successfully upload";
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

**OR**

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath);
```

Here, 
**photo** will be your image, you want to save.

**$destinationPath**: Where you want to store your uploaded image

**$fileName**: Your image filename (optional)

Your Form, through which you are uploading the file, should be in this format:

```
{!! Form::open(array('name'=>'create', 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'url'=>'some/path')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

See, if that helps. (For More info see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files))

Comment: this does not work the error is that..'FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 153:'
Call to a member function move() on a non-object.....

Comment: do print_r(Input::file('photo')); and see if you're getting image object.

Comment: no it is show blanked nothing is print.if i do `dd($file)` then print null

Comment: It means that image is not received by controller or uploaded

Comment: if i use `public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }` then show image name and token number showed.

Comment: it has main error `FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 152:
Call to a member function move() on a non-object`

Comment: you are sending just the image name, search how to upload image