# Upload Profile Picture in Laravel Registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

Please help me to add upload profile picture on laravel 5.2 registration form.
I use Auth for my registration and login, but made some modification there.

this is my register.blade.php view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Pendaftaran Akun Baru</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!} 

<!-- start of nip -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nip') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nomor Induk Pegawai</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nip" value="{{ old('nip') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('nip'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nip') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- end of nip -->

<!-- start of nama -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nama') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nama</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" value="{{ old('nama') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('nama'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nama') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- end of nama -->

<!-- start of email -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Alamat E-mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

<!-- end of email -->

<!-- start of password -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- end of password -->

<!-- start of konfirmasi -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Konfirmasi Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- end of konfirmasi -->                        

<!-- start of foto -->
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('avatar') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">F o t o</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <div id="kv-avatar-errors" class="center-block" style="width:800px;display:none">
                                </div>

                                <div class="kv-avatar" style="width:200px">
                                    <input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" class="file-loading">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
<!-- end of foto -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Daftar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is my eloquent app\Daftarpegawai.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Daftarpegawai extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
        'nip', 'nama', 'email', 'password', 'foto',   
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'status', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

and this is my AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Daftarpegawai;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nip' => 'required|max:20',
            'nama' => 'required|max:255',
            'avatar' => 'mimes:jpg',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:daftarpegawais',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Daftarpegawai::create([
            'nip' => $data['nip'],
            'nama' => $data['nama'],
            'foto' => $data['avatar'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am new in learning laravel
i've tried some methods that i found here with the same problem, but nothing works for me

Comment: Thank you for pasting the code and formatting your question nicely! If you have any details on technical errors that you are facing or any observations about what doesn't work, it will help others in answering.

Comment: where is the code that store the avatar? if you want to know how handle uploading files thats another question see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218651/what-is-the-function-to-upload-images-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: @dubes it's not work. When i submit the data, it shows the form again, it appears that there is problem with the photo.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data->hasFile('avatar'))
{
    $destinationPath = 'path/to/upload/the/file'
    $imgName = 'yourimagename.jpg'
    $data->avatar->move($destinationPath, $imgName)
    $path = $destinationPath . '/' . $imgName
}

DaftarPegawai::create([
    'foto' => $path
])
```

Comment: I've tried to put the code on authcontroller, but it doesn't work too
the label color for the input change to warning, but no error message appear

Comment: what about the folder access? does it have to has a write access on guest? it has drwxr-xr-x on /public/img folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as your POST request code for uploading avatar to user profile

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
       'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
 ]);
   $user = Auth::user();
  $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request()->avatar-
  >getClientOriginalExtension();
  $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);
  $user->avatar = $avatarName;
  $user->save();
  return back()
  ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

Source : Detailed tutorial https://www.5balloons.info/upload-profile-picture-avatar-laravel-5-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still facing problem, try using the following codes! Hope it will work...

```
$avatar = $data['avatar'];
$extension = $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
$avatar_name  = time() . '.' . $extension;
$avatar->move(base_path('public/images/avatars/'), $avatar_name);

return User::create([
    'avatar' => $avatar_name,
]);
```